# Text on label not set when window appears

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I've made a small Cocoa Application with a custom *MyWindow.xib* and a *MyWindowController*. The window contains a NSTextField (label) and from my *AppDelegate* I'm initializing this controller and it's view, setting a text on the label and displays the window:

```
self.controller =[[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
[self.controller setText:@"My text"];
[self.controller showWindow:self];
```

But the default "Label" text is still displayed, when the windows appear. Why?

My sample project can be downloaded here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00611347759347594342.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your label is not actually visual yet, so changing the text does nothing. One way you can get around this is to have a string property in your controller and set that:

```
self.controller.textForLabel = @"My text";
```

Then in your `viewWillAppear:`in your controller's .m you can set the text:

```
[self setText:self.textForLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project you're changing the text before showing the window, which is done before the initialization. Just switch this:

```
[self.controller setText:@"My text"];
[self.controller showWindow:self];
```

to

```
[self.controller showWindow:self];
[self.controller setText:@"My text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve it:
Replace two lines of code, set text after showing window, so it should look like:

```
[self.controller showWindow:self];
[self.controller setText:@"My text"];
```

Other way is to change your label text in MyWindowController.m file inside of "-(void)windowDidLoad" function.